# how can i send image via activities in android

Tags: java, android

I have an application that allow users to choose picture from native gallery then I show this image in image view widget.

My question is:
1-i have to send this image to another Activity. How can i do it.

2-in the receiver Activity i should show it in image view widget as in image not link or Something

I tried this code but it gives me a RunTime Error

```
   Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
   view.draw(new Canvas(image));
   String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), image,"title", null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the below steps...

Uri uri = null;
1) on any click event use the below code to open native gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),0);
```

This will open gallery select picture will return you to your activity. OnActivity result.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
switch (requestCode) {
case 0:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    try {
    uri = Uri.parse(data.getDataString());
    imageView.setImageUri(uri);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }}
    break;
    }
}
```

2) Also instead of passing the image you can pass the URI to next activity as you pass string and inthe secont activity you get it using intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Second.class);
i.putExtra("URI", uri.toString() );
startActivity(i);
```

and in the second activity

```
String uri = getIntent().getStringExtra("URI");
```

Now you have string just set it to the image view like below

```
imageView.setImageUri(Uri.parse(uri));
```

Comment: i already did the gallery part but i need to send it to another activity and show it as image. can you please give the code that doing this step.

Answer (score 0):

Use intent putExtra and send uri of the image user selected in Acvtivity1 and in second activity use intent getExtra to read the uri

Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325248/308251

Comment: ok this is how can i send a normal value but what about the image?i think i should doing some transfer to Bitmap then convert it to normal image to show it in second Activity,please give me the code to doing this step

Comment: but why you need to send bitmap, you can send uri of selected bitmap it is more optimized, is there any usecase why you prefer to send bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not what you're looking for and it's a bit poor but saved my life when I needed to pass objects between Activities.

```
    public class MagatzemImg {
         private static MagatzemImg instance = null;
         private static Bitmap img;

         public MagatzemImg(){ 
            img=null; 
         }

         public static MagatzemImg getInstance() {
            if (instance == null)
            instance = new MagatzemImg();
            return instance;
         }

         public static void setImg(Bitmap im){ 
            img = im; 
         }
         public static Bitmap getImg(){
             Bitmap imgAux = img;
             img = null;
             return imgAux;
         }
    }
```

And then from the new activity:

```
    MagatzemImg.getInstance();
    image = MagatzemImg.getImg();
```

You can 'assure' to the new Activity that the image exists inside the Static Class through `putExtra("image",true)` or something else you prefer, like checking if the "image" is null.